# How can I find items from drawbale background file in an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-drawable, android-theme, android-background

I have an activity with **no** layout. I set it like a theme directly in `AndroidManifest`:

> android:theme="@style/MyTheme">

My theme contains only a background:

```
<style name="MyTheme"
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

And this is the background file which contains only two items:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/colorDarkGrey"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_icon_red"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_icon_red"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_icon_blue"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_icon_blue"/>
</layer-list>
```

How can I find (`ic_icon_red` and `ic_icon_blue`) in my activity so I can do the logic I want.`findViewById()` doesn't work in this case. Thanks!

Comment: @AkashPatel I want to apply logic for the items within the `background` file. So you say it is not possible at all?

Comment: Hi, once try this.   ((LayerDrawable)getDrawable()).setDrawableByLayerId()

Answer (score 0):

That should be like this if i understood correct.

```
@Test
public void testDrawable(){
    Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    LayerDrawable backGroundLayer = (LayerDrawable) appContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background);
    assertNotNull(backGroundLayer.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id. ic_icon_red));
}
```

above is just test case to check, you can use like this.

```
LayerDrawable backGroundLayer = (LayerDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background);
Drawable drawable = backGroundLayer.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id. ic_icon_red)
```

Comment: `getDrawable()` it's deprecated but let's say this won't be a problem. The problem is, how can set on click listener on that item since it's a `Drawable` and not a `View`? Thank you!